# Toggle between the creation and destruction of a table row jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I am working on a drop down feature for a table that populates its data using mysql. When user clicks button it will create a new table row under the current one containing the button. The desired goal is to make it so the button will delete the newly created row if pressed again, right now it will just keep creating additional new ones. Here is what I have so far:

**Table (PHP):**

```
while($sound=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='40' class='player'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='beats/".$sound['downloadlink']."' class='sm2_button'>Play/</a></td>";
    echo '<td width="250" class="name">'.$sound['name'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="red date">'.$sound['date'].'</span></td>';
    echo "<td width='88' class='bpm'>".$sound['bpm']." B.P.M.</td>";
    echo "<td width='72' class='length'>".$sound['length']."</td>";
    echo "<td width='275' class='keywords'>".$sound['keywords']."</td>";
    echo "<td width='96' class='buy'><img class='button' src='99cents.png'/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

**Create new table row:**

```
$(".button").on('click', function(){
    $(this).parents('tr').after('<tr><td height="100" colspan="6"><img src="mp31.png"/></td></tr>');
});
```

**Trying to toggle between the creation and removal of table row:**

```
 $(".button").on('click', function(){

    .toggle($(this).parents('tr').after('<tr><td height="100" colspan="6"><img src="mp31.png"/></td></tr>'); : .remove());
});
```

Comment: At first glance, I would as a user expect the NEW row to perhaps enclose the "delete me" functionality described.

Comment: A good TIP (I have got approved my answers about that): You cannot add only TR to table. DOM manipulation will drop this TR out of TABLE. What you should do is re-rendering whole table before putting it to DOM. 
Imo better sollution is to use DIV with display:table-cell etc instead of any usage of tables (browsers shouldnt allow you to inject rows to rendered table but should let you erase that table and put new render of it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started to answer prior to your posting the table so this is the simple markup I used:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr class="adder">
        <td>I am the adder row</td>
        <td width='96' class='buy'>
            <img class='button' src='99cents.png' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I then used this:

```
$('#mytable').on('click', ".button", function () {
    alert('Got the click');
    var thisRow = $(this).parents('tr.adder');
    var hasNextRow = thisRow.next('tr.added').length;
    if (hasNextRow) {
        alert("removing");
        thisRow.next('tr.added').remove();
    } else {
        alert("adding");
        $(this).parents('tr.adder').after('<tr class="added"><td height="100" colspan="6" ><img src="mp31.png"/>howdy i am new</td></tr>');
    }
});
```

Test it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/d6peafsp/1/

Answer (score 0):

Actually that you are using `jQuery.toogle` is not correct.

This is a simple example to use it giving a valid/correct `CSS selector`:

```
$('.toggle-btn').on('click', function(){
    $('tr:last').toggle();
});
```

**[See JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4wkaequx/)**

**EDIT:**

This other **[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4wkaequx/2/)** does the same thing but the first time adds the row in the table

Comment: Hello Leo, that is not exactly what I am trying to do. The <tr> shouldn't exist on page until a user clicks the creation button, I am trying to make it so after <tr> is created it will delete if button is pressed again.

Comment: @Jeff Yes, I believed so, that is why I added the second demo. in which the TR element is added (see the edit)

Comment: Hey Leo, I added some more info to my question, I am populating my table data using MySql and a loop, The <tr> has to be under $(this).parents('tr') of the image with class button

Comment: Uuhmm? the javascript part to create the row is the same ... I believe you will need to integrate it with the way that you send your mysql data to JavaScript side