# Load HTML content in a newly created table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a web page of very neatly structured data.  There are about 20 "parents" and about 1000 "children".  Right now I show a huge table of all the children.  What I want to do is display the table of parents, and have a button/toggle for each row that when clicked would:

- add a row beneath that parent in the table
- execute a GET request to display an HTML table of children in that row

on the next click the button/toggle would remove that row from the table

My HTML looks like this:

```
<table id="tableofparents">
  <tr>
    <th>Buttons</th>
    <th>Col B</th>
    <th>Col C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="adder" id="101">
    <td id="101" class="toggleChildren">Button</td>  # unique id per row already exists
    <td>Info Field 1</td>
    <td>Info Field 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="adder" id="202">
    <td id="202" class="toggleChildren">Button</td>
    <td>Info Field 1</td>
    <td>Info Field 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I figured out the code to toggle creation/deletion of a new table row here from here - [Toggle between the creation and destruction of a table row jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793126/toggle-between-the-creation-and-destruction-of-a-table-row-jquery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $('#tableofparents').on('click', ".toggleChildren", function () {
            var thisRow = $(this).parents('tr.adder');
            var hasNextRow = thisRow.next('tr.added').length;
            if (hasNextRow) {
                thisRow.next('tr.added').remove();
            } else {
                $(this).parents('tr.adder').after('<tr class="added"><td colspan="3" >This is where I want to load the HTML of the children via a GET request</td></tr>');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

When I click on the button in the first row, it now toggles the addition of a new table row.  But I also need that same click to execute a GET request to http://example.com/childdata?id=101 and load the HTML from that request into the new row, and I just can't figure out how to do that.

Is there a way to load HTML into the newly created row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `else` statement you can do this:

```
var parent = $(this).parents('tr.adder'), id = parent.attr('id');
$.get('http://example.com/childdata?id='+id, function(html) {
    parent.after('<tr class="added"><td colspan="3" >'+html+'</td></tr>');
});
```

I hope this will help you.